# routerLink adding question mark in url?

Tags: angular, routes, angular-routerlink

I want to have route something like this : `www.test.com?procesId=12` .

This is my current routerLink:

But right now i get this value :

```
www.test.com/123
```

Any suggestion how can i add in url `?procesId = 12` with `routerLink` ?

I tried:

But i dont get question mark in url and also i get an error:

> Cannot match any routes.

I know that i can get question mark when i use params but i want to use it with routerLink, because thats the way they use it on this project.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

you can use query params in routerlink like below

```
[routerLink]="['']" [queryParams]="{ procesId : 12 }"
```